# How to import images to google colab

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

I'm starting to use google colab I'm I want to load a set of images for processing from my laptop.

I have tried this:

[image]

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: embedded NUL character
```

Which is then the right process to import the images?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
from io import BytesIO
uploaded = files.upload()
im = Image.open(BytesIO(uploaded['test.png']))
```

This is because the upload() command doesn't save the file. It stores the content in uploaded dictionary.

Or you can this use this function to upload files. It will both upload and save them.

```
def upload_files():
  from google.colab import files
  uploaded = files.upload()
  for k, v in uploaded.items():
    open(k, 'wb').write(v)
  return list(uploaded.keys())
```

Comment: Now I', getting this: "TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str"

Comment: Oh.. it should be BytesIO, not StringIO. Sorry, now corrected.

Answer (score 5):

Import the libraries:

```
from google.colab import files
from IPython.display import Image
```

Upload the file:

`uploaded = files.upload()`

Load the image:

`Image("foo.png", width=600)`